# Date calculations in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a very basic question reg date calculations in Oracle SQL.

I have been using the following logic to calculate the age and identify records with age>=75:

```
(Date1 - Date2) / 365.25 >= 75
```

However the above logic was calculating the age incorrectly  for the following scenario:

```
Date1 = MM-DD-2016
Date2 = MM-DD-1947
```

Although, here the age is 69, it was showing up in my output. After I added to_date for both the dates, the query did not bring this record.

My question is: I have not used to_date earlier in this query and was working for the other records fine, but why has it failed for this scenario?

Edit: I wanted to add, looks like my database records values as below when partial dates are entered:
Date1 is 6/15/1947 
Date2 is 6/15/2016

Comment: Have you looked at what your calculation actually produces for those dates? Can you give specific dates that appear to match your filter? And... are you sure the older date is 1947, not the wrong century - are you querying/displaying dates with four-digit years (and allowing a minus sign; `SYYYY`)?

Comment: These are the dates in the database, Date1 is 6/15/1947 and Date2 is 6/15/2016 without the month and days, looks like my db takes these values when partial dates are entered. I honestly was no sure of why it did not work and just tried the to_date function and it seemed to work. Still cant figure out why the initial query did not work?

Comment: If they're already dates then `to_date()` shouldn't be used. Are you sure the year hasn't been entered as -1947? Query your table for `where date2 = to_date('-1947-06-15', 'SYYYY-MM-DD')`.

Comment: Yes, I just verified it using the where condition above, the dates are 6/15/1947 and 6/15/2016.

Comment: If querying with that filter returned a values then the date is -1947, and is being displayed as +1947. Guess I should have said: `select to_char(date2, 'SYYYY-MM-DD') from your_table where date2 = date '-1947-06-15'`. The `S` part of the date format model will show if the year is positive or negative. But if the filter finds it then it is negative.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `add_months()` function:

```
where date1 >= add_months(date2, 75*12)
```

The months calculations are more precise -- for years -- than the ones based on days.

Alternatively, you can use `interval`:

```
where date1 >= date2 + interval '75' year
```

Comment: The interval calculation will fail if `date2` is February 29th, sadly, with "ORA-01839: date not valid for month specified".. So I'd go with the first one.

Comment: Thank you, but can someone explain why my initial query did not work? I am trying to understand how Oracle calculates using this query.

Comment: Your original query is close but 365.25 days per year is an approximation.  12 months is more precise (although it might have hiccups on leap days).

Answer (score 1):

The only way i can see you'd get that result is if you have a date stored as -1947 instead of 1947:

```
with t (Date1, Date2) as (
  select date '2016-06-15', add_months(date '2016-06-15', -12*level)
  from dual
  connect by level <= 80
  union all
  select date '2016-06-15', date '-1947-06-15'
  from dual
)
select * from t
where (Date1 - Date2) / 365.25 >= 75;

DATE1      DATE2    
---------- ----------
06/15/2016 06/15/1941
06/15/2016 06/15/1940
06/15/2016 06/15/1939
06/15/2016 06/15/1938
06/15/2016 06/15/1937
06/15/2016 06/15/1936
06/15/2016 06/15/1947
```

That last record looks like it shouldn't be there. But my NLS_DATE_FORMAT mask is MM/DD/YYYY (to match what you're seeing); if I make it show the sign of the year it makes more sense:

```
alter session set nls_date_format = 'MM/DD/SYYYY';

with t (Date1, Date2) as (
  select date '2016-06-15', add_months(date '2016-06-15', -12*level)
  from dual
  connect by level <= 80
  union all
  select date '2016-06-15', date '-1947-06-15'
  from dual
)
select * from t
where (Date1 - Date2) / 365.25 >= 75;

DATE1         DATE2       
------------- -------------
6/15/ 2016    6/15/ 1941   
6/15/ 2016    6/15/ 1940   
6/15/ 2016    6/15/ 1939   
6/15/ 2016    6/15/ 1938   
6/15/ 2016    6/15/ 1937   
6/15/ 2016    6/15/ 1936   
6/15/ 2016    6/15/-1947
```

Or even better:

```
with t (Date1, Date2) as (
  select date '2016-06-15', add_months(date '2016-06-15', -12*level)
  from dual
  connect by level <= 80
  union all
  select date '2016-06-15', date '-1947-06-15'
  from dual
)
select to_char(date1, 'SYYYY-MM-DD') as date1, to_char(date2, 'SYYYY-MM-DD') as date2
from t
where (Date1 - Date2) / 365.25 >= 75;

DATE1       DATE2     
----------- -----------
 2016-06-15  1941-06-15
 2016-06-15  1940-06-15
 2016-06-15  1939-06-15
 2016-06-15  1938-06-15
 2016-06-15  1937-06-15
 2016-06-15  1936-06-15
 2016-06-15 -1947-06-15
```

So you can see the date from -1947 is shown, but the date from 1947 is not. And that is a lot more than 75 years ago:

```
select months_between(date '2016-06-15', date '-1947-06-15')/12 as years from dual;

     YEARS
----------
      3963
```

---

The reason adding `to_date()` around your values stopped the record appearing is that you would be implicitly converting the date to a string and then back to a date, using the same `MM/DD/YYYY` format mask. The intermediate string would *not* include the minus sign, so `date '-1947-06-15'` would become the string `06/15/1947`. When that is converted back to a date the sign is still missing, and the string `06/15/1947` becomes `date '1947-06-15'`. Which is now only 69 years ago, not 3963 years ago.